# Reshaping Pandas Dataframe slicing columns and adding them as rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas dataframe named 'trdf' with the shape [1 row X 420 columns].

```
      0                                                  1           2    \
0  B0742F7GT8  Stone & Beam Modern Tripod Floor Lamp, 61"H, W...  2018-04-22   

       3        4       5      6   7       8   9            ...            \
0  24-Apr-2018  100.00%  17.06%  0.00%   5  66.67%   8          ...             

  410  411 412       413 414 415    416      417 418                    419  
0  56  161  -8  -166.67%   0   1  0.00%  100.00%   8  Planned Replenishment
```

I want to slice every 20 columns from last and add the column values as new row values. here is my code :

```
for i in range(420,20,-20):
    trdf.append(trdf.loc[:,i:i-20])
print(trdf)
```

However, the dataframe is still same with respect to shape and values. Where's the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe first create `MultiIndex` in columns and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df.columns = [df.columns % 20, df.columns // 20]
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Or use numpy solution with `reshape`, but finally all data are `string`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(20, 21))
```

---

If want use your solution create list of one row DataFrames and [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
L = []
for i in range(420,20,-20):
    #change order for selecting 
    df2 = df.loc[:,i-20:i]
    #for same columns
    df2.columns = range(20)
    L.append(df2)

df1 = pd.concat(L)
```

Also if need expected output join from last columns to first:

```
df.columns = [df.columns % 20, 20-df.columns // 20]
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

And:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(20, 21)[::-1])
```